# How to get text from input type="text"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, text

HTML:

```
<div>
 <label for="mytags">Add tags:</label>
 <input name="mytags" id="mytags" type="text" value="1111, 2222, 3333,">
</div>
```

JS:

```
  this.tags = $("#mytags")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

But I receive text from **value="1111, 2222, 3333,"** and not the text that I type in the field.

How to solve?

This codes from  [uploader API 3 javascript](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/upload_video.js)
Original code is a:

```
var UploadVideo = function() {
  /**
   * The array of tags for the new YouTube video.
   *
   * @attribute tags
   * @type Array.<string>
   * @default ['google-cors-upload']
   */
  this.tags = ['youtube-cors-upload'];
...
```

Maybe you have any other idea how to get tags from input type="text"?

Comment: At what time is your JS run? On page load? In an event handler?

Comment: How is that javascript executed?  It will return the value of the input at the time that the code is run; if you're expecting it to update the contents of `this.tags` whenever the input changes you'll need to use a `change` event handler on the input.  (I'm also not quite clear on why you're using map and get here, instead of just `this.tags = $('#mytags').val()`)

Comment: **this.tags = $('#mytags').val()** not working. Updated my first post. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please understand that *not working* is **a completely useless comment by you**.

Comment: Please don't post a solution in your question section. If one answer solved your issue, accept it by clicking the checkmark or post an answer on your own.

Comment: Edited and removed solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Note:

```
this.tags = ['youtube-cors-upload']
```

Notice `this.tags` is an `Array`. If you overwrite that with the `value` from the `input`, it is going to become a `String` instead. Are you sure that's what you want/need?

If, though, your problem is as simple as you describe, a solution like this **must** work:

```js
var mytags = document.getElementById('mytags');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var getAttrValue = document.getElementById('getAttrValue');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // this reads whatever is currently in the input
  alert(mytags.value);
})

getAttrValue.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // this reads whatever is set in the HTML attribute value on the element
  alert(mytags.getAttribute('value'));
})
```

```html
<div>
 <label for="mytags">Add tags:</label>
 <input name="mytags" id="mytags" type="text" value="1111, 2222, 3333,">
 <button id="btn">Get Tags value from input</button>
 <button id="getAttrValue">Get the attribute value instead of the property value</button>
</div>
```

If you need to parse the input field so each comma-separated text becomes an array element in `this.tags`, this is what you'd need to do:

```js
var tags = ['whatever-this-is'];
var tags2 = ['whatever-this-is'];
var mytags = document.getElementById('mytags');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // this reads whatever is currently in the input
  // and splits the values into an array
  tags = mytags.value.replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
  // if all you want is an array with one element
  // that is whatever was in the input, do this:
  tags2 = [mytags.value];
  console.log(tags);
  console.log(tags2);
})
```

```html
<div>
 <label for="mytags">Add tags:</label>
 <input name="mytags" id="mytags" type="text" value="1111, 2222, 3333,">
 <button id="btn">Get Tags value from input and put them in tags array</button>
</div>
```

If your problem is something else you need to add more information to your question and I will try to adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: `var mytags = document.getElementById('mytags');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(mytags.value);
})` working fine for alert. But how to transfer and equalize this value **mytags.value** in/for **this.tags = ['need add here"mytags.value"'];**

Comment: I have added that in my second snippet.

Comment: Is your question answered with this? If yes, pick an answer. If no, please specify in the comments what is going wrong/missing.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Problem solved after carefully read post by **@sventschui**. I add code **tags: $("#mytags").val().split(/[ ,]+/).filter(Boolean)** on other line in upload_video.js after **UploadVideo.prototype.uploadFile = function(file) {** and all working fine.

Comment: So none of the answers given solves your problem, or pushed you in the right direction? And this comment solved it *At what time is your JS run? On page load? In an event handler?*?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your followup edit, it looks like you're not just trying to retrieve the input field's value, you're trying to convert that value into an array.  The `map().get()` stuff you attempted does return an array, but only a single element array (because you're handing it a single string value) -- it looks like instead you intend to split that string on the commas:

```js
var splitTags = function() {
  this.tags = $("#mytags")
    .val() // get the field value
    .split(/\s?,\s?/) // split on commas and (optionally) whitespace
    .filter(Boolean); // remove empty elements (caused by leading or trailing commas)
  console.log(this.tags);
  return this.tags;
}

// demo:
splitTags();
$('#mytags').on("change", splitTags);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="mytags">Add tags:</label>
  <input name="mytags" id="mytags" type="text" value="1111, 2222, 3333,">
</div>
```

Comment: not working for me :( I want only receive text that I type in the field with ID **mytags** and send to this.tags = **?** without split or replaces.

Comment: That would be a simple `this.tags = $('#mytags').val()`, then.    If that's not working for you please explain what does happen when you try; just saying "it's not working" doesn't give us anything to go on.  Are you getting error messages? different output than expected? Something else?